# jquery .fadeIn .delay .fadeOut - not fading out

Tags: java, jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

Not sure what i'm doing wrong but these divs fade in correctly but don't fadeOut!

They're intended to be on structured timeline in time with a mp3, hence the long delay times!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div { position: absolute; width: 60px; height: 60px; float: left; display:none; }
.first { background-color: #3f3; left: 0;}
.second { background-color: #33f; left: 80px;}
.third { background-color: #3f3; left: 120px;}
.fourth { background-color: #33f; left: 300px;}
.fifth { background-color: #3f3; left: 400;}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.slide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button>Run</button></p>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
<div class="fourth"></div>
<div class="fifth"></div>

<script>
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("div.first").delay(15060).show("puff", {}, 300).delay(116010).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.second").delay(40230).show("puff", {},300).delay(28990).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.third").delay(46180).show("puff", {},300).delay(27880).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.fourth").delay(71070).show("puff", {},300).delay(42050).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.fifth").delay(110080).show("puff", {},300).delay(17050).fadeOut(300);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Mathletics i tried what you suggested but it broke it completely, any ideas what i may of done wrong? Sorry muddling through with my limited knowledge of Jquery

Script changed but still not working?

```
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
  $("div.first").delay(200).show(300, "puff", function() {
 $(this).delay(116010).fadeOut(300);  });
   $("div.first").delay(40230).show(300, "puff", function() {
 $(this).delay(28990).fadeOut(300);  });
   $("div.first").delay(46180).show(300, "puff", function() {
 $(this).delay(27880).fadeOut(300);  });
   $("div.first").delay(71070).show(300, "puff", function() {
 $(this).delay(42050).fadeOut(300);  });
   $("div.first").delay(110080).show(300, "puff", function() {
 $(this).delay(17050).fadeOut(300);  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks veeTrain, it almost works except i need them to come in at specific times as well as leave at specific times, here's how i changed the code to try to do that! Thanks in advance it's much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div { position: absolute; width: 60px; height: 60px; float: left; display:none; }
.first { background-color: #3f3; left: 0;}
.second { background-color: #33f; left: 80px;}
.third { background-color: #3f3; left: 120px;}
.fourth { background-color: #33f; left: 300px;}
.fifth { background-color: #3f3; left: 400;}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.slide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button>Run</button></p>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
<div class="fourth"></div>
<div class="fifth"></div>

<script>
    $("button").click(function() {
        console.log("hi");
      $("div.first").delay(15060).show(300);
      $("div.second").delay(40230).show(300);
      $("div.third").delay(46180).show(300);
      $("div.fourth").delay(71070).show(300);
      $("div.fifth").delay(110080).show(300);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div.first").fadeOut(300);
        }, 116010);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div.second").fadeOut(300);
        }, 28990);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div.third").fadeOut(300);
        }, 27880);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div.fourth").fadeOut(300);
        }, 42050);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("div.fifth").fadeOut(300);
        }, 17050);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They fade in and never fade out?  Which browsers have you tested this on?  When they do fade in, do they just stay on your screen never to fade out?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what .show("puff", {},300) would mean -- http://api.jquery.com/show/  ??

Comment: this is on the latest version of Chrome, they fade in but never fadeout... It worked until i added in a delay before .show("puff...

Comment: Be sure to let me know by commenting if my solution didn't work for you appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also execute a setTimeout operation like so:

```
$("div.first").delay(15060).show(300, "puff");
setTimeout(function() {
    $("div.first").fadeOut(300);
}, 116010);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfHr8/) showing an example. (Note, doesn't include your 'puff' operation)

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfHr8/1/) shows with what your timings might be.

If I'm understanding your intentions, you'll want the elements to be queued up to hide x seconds AFTER it is first shown. These examples don't perform that but you should be able to make the calculations yourself and hide the elements exactly when you want to by adding the time for the initial delay.

E.g.: `fade in after 5 seconds; fade out after 5 seconds`

could become `fade in after 5 seconds and fade out after *10* seconds`

Comment: Hey it almost works see the edit i made at the bottom, above!

Comment: Oh i should say what didn't work for me, was that the first one appears, then doesn't disappear, the next ones come in at the right time but then disappear instantly.

Comment: @BenVickers; great points about them disappearing instantly. That was the point I was making at the end of my 'answer'; I updated it to mention that you would need to manually decide to increase the timeout by whatever the first delayed display was. I.e., 5 seconds delay to show and 5 seconds delay to hide would be a delay of 5 and a set timeout of 10. This probably isn't the ideal solution but I think it becomes workable. Why are your timeouts so _long_? Newest iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/BfHr8/3/

Comment: Wow okay this is great, thank you! Sorry for misunderstanding, i've noticed that my timings for timeout are a bit wrong but think this is my mistake since i set the timeout based on the whole length of time it's on screen and subtracted the timein time. 

the:
     $("div.first").fadeOut(300);
}, **116010**); 

applies just to the time it's showing right? 

The reason this code is so absurd and they're so long, is because it's for an artwork, where different videos popup in time with the music >_<

Comment: @BenVickers; ah! Sounds cool; I hope you'll post a link to the final project. The timeouts are in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second). Start with this simpler example to get a feel for the timings and then proceed from there. This should make things simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/BfHr8/6/

Comment: Okay great, yeah that makes sense thank you for your incredible help! Will definitely post a link here when it's done :)

Answer (score 2):

You should fire the `fadeout` as a callback, like so:

```
  $("div.first").delay(15060).show(300, "puff", function() {
     $(this).delay(116010).fadeOut(300);
  });
```

Comment: tried but broke it, did i implement it wrong? See above. Thanks!